# Start Audio by clicking button, stop it by scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, scroll

I'm working on a site with 3 sections (Home, Music Player, About)

In the home section when you click the Listen Now button is scrolls down to the next section and automatically starts playing the music, That works perfectly.

When you scroll from the second section the the third section the music player needs to stop playing.

I found some code that turns the audio down as you scroll. It would be ideal to fade out and pause the audio if you scroll the the next section, and start and fade back in if you scroll up. The second script area is whats causing the problem. Here's a link to the site if that helps.

```
<header id="mast">
<hgroup>
    <img class="main-logo" src="<?php echo $options['main_logo']; ?>" />
    <a href="#" class="btn s-waypoint" id="listen-btn">Listen Here </a>
</hgroup>
```

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('listen-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('music-player').play();
    });
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElm = $('#music-player').get(0);
    audioElm.play();

    var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        audioElm.volume = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / height;
        console.log(audioElm.volume);
    });
});
</script>


<div id="main" class="e-waypoint topo">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" role="main">
        <section>
            <article>
                <audio controls id="music-player">
                    <source src="http://rob.peytongregory.com/wp-content/themes/robertfoster/audio/robert-foster.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
            </article>     
        </section>
    </div><!-- /#primary.site-content -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- /#main -->
```

Comment: link to the site I'm workinng on. http://rob.peytongregory.com

Comment: Personally, I think I would do this by finding the offset of the section from the bottom/top. That way even if the user uses the scrollbar, spacebar, or w.e the user does it still works.